# How can I make it so my tripod's camera holder isn't loose and floppy?

Tags: tripod

I obtained a tripod awhile ago, but have only recently begun to use it. My problem with it is that the camera top is, as the title says, loose and floppy. The base legs, and such adjustments, work perfectly fine. It's just that I cannot seem to prevent the top component from flailing over at a minimal bump of force. How can I resolve this?

[image]

This is the part in question.
Here are photos of the entire tripod at a few different angles.

[image]
[image] [image]
<sub>Click for full size</sub>

Comment: Is the problem with the part that says SLIK (the tripod head) or the ¿phone holder? that says Bower?

Comment: @xiota The part marked SLIK, tripod head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three points marked in this picture are Hex Nuts -

[image]

they require a hex, or Allen key, probably 4mm, which come is a variety of shapes & styles, from $£€0.50 to $£€10

[image][image]
[image][image]
<sub>Click for larger size</sub>

If you're not certain what size it is [my 4mm is a guess based on experience, but still a guess] then you can buy really cheap sets of these, even in the local supermarket or DIY store, for about $£€1.50.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. It's a good thing I keep an a wrap up Allen wrench set lying around. Tightened up my tripod in a jiffy. I declare this issue now resolved!